# Error while connecting to DB2 zOS Database using Java

Tags: java, db2-zos

Getting the below error while connecting to DB2 zOS server.
Can someone please help?
We have used Jar file db2jcc4.jar for the same along with other JDBC related Jar files.
Do I need to use "db2jcc_license_cu.jar" file as well?
I am getting difficulties in resolving this.

We tried db2jcc.jar as well, but no success.

Java code is as below.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class DB2Connection {

    public DB2Connection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
        String url="jdbc:db2://ip-address:port/mydb";

        String user="user";
        String password="password";

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            //Load class into memory
            Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
            System.out.println("**** Loaded the JDBC driver");
            //Establish connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(connection!=null){
                System.out.println("Connected successfully.");
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                   // e.printStackTrace();
                    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + errors.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    }

Error while validating the given DB details com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2057][11264][4.11.77] The application server rejected establishment of the connection.
An attempt was made to access a database, ABCP, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2057][11264][4.11.77] The application server rejected establishment of the connection.
An attempt was made to access a database, ABCP, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:319)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:365)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.u(ab.java:1674)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.n(ab.java:536)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:343)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:115)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.m(b.java:1242)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1113)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.d(b.java:696)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:682)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:367)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:307)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:460)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at beans.KBSourceTargetDefBean.testConnection(KBSourceTargetDefBean.java:1136)
        at beans.KBSourceTargetDefBean.setCommand(KBSourceTargetDefBean.java:435)
        at com.solix.controller.BeanController.setCommand(BeanController.java:970)
        at com.solix.controller.BeanController.loadModel(BeanController.java:407)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at filter.ValidateTokenFilter.doFilter(ValidateTokenFilter.java:121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at filter.UserValidateFilter.doFilter(UserValidateFilter.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at filter.GenerateTokenFilter.doFilter(GenerateTokenFilter.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/171172/comibmdb2jccamdisconnectnontransientconnectionexce/ might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I could not add comment due to not enough reputation, but it sounds like perhaps "ABCP" is not the correct database name.
Take a look here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21443723
It lists ways to find database name.
If you are using correct name, then double check the port.

As far as the license question.
In my apps I use both db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_ciuz.jar
I believe you need _ciuz,jar to access DB2 z/OS not _cu.jar,  but usually license issue results in a different error from the one you show.